# Error to connect my Postgres database to Spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm developing a simple app using Spring boot and decided to use PostgreSQL to store my data.
I opted to use elephantSQL to host my DB but I'm having this error when trying to connect with my Spring app
[image]

I already connected using the pgadmin4 and everything worked fine.

Here's my ElephantSQL data
[image]

Here's my application.properties
[image]

Here's my pom.xml
[image]

Please, any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was writing the host URL wrong

it should be "jdbc:postgresql://" instead of "jdbc:postgres://"